# during sails lift it throw error

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

hi i am new to sails and passport js i am trying authentication using passport js in sails but while am adding passport.js in config folder it give an error..any one know how to resolve this issu..

```
Here is my error

C:\Users\sachinn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\include-all\lib\help-include-all-sync.js:281
              throw e;
              ^

`include-all` attempted to `require(E:\myApi\config\passport.js)`, but an error occurred::
Details:TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a function to retrieve jwt from requests (see option jwtFromRequest)
    at new JwtStrategy (E:\myApi\node_modules\passport-jwt\lib\strategy.js:39:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\myApi\config\passport.js:68:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

**passort.js**

```
/**
 * Passport configuration file where you should configure strategies
 */
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;

var EXPIRES_IN_MINUTES = 60 * 24;
var SECRET = process.env.tokenSecret || "4ukI0uIVnB3iI1yxj646fVXSE3ZVk4doZgz6fTbNg7jO41EAtl20J5F7Trtwe7OM";
var ALGORITHM = "HS256";
var ISSUER = "nozus.com";
var AUDIENCE = "nozus.com";

/**
 * Configuration object for local strategy
 */
var LOCAL_STRATEGY_CONFIG = {
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: false
};

/**
 * Configuration object for JWT strategy
 */
var JWT_STRATEGY_CONFIG = {
  secretOrKey: SECRET,
  issuer : ISSUER,
  audience: AUDIENCE,
  passReqToCallback: false
};

/**
 * Triggers when user authenticates via local strategy
 */
function _onLocalStrategyAuth(email, password, next) {
  User.findOne({email: email})
    .exec(function (error, user) {
      if (error) return next(error, false, {});

      if (!user) return next(null, false, {
        code: 'E_USER_NOT_FOUND',
        message: email + ' is not found'
      });

      // TODO: replace with new cipher service type
      if (!CipherService.comparePassword(password, user))
        return next(null, false, {
          code: 'E_WRONG_PASSWORD',
          message: 'Password is wrong'
        });

      return next(null, user, {});
    });
}

/**
 * Triggers when user authenticates via JWT strategy
 */
function _onJwtStrategyAuth(payload, next) {
  var user = payload.user;
  return next(null, user, {});
}

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(LOCAL_STRATEGY_CONFIG, _onLocalStrategyAuth));
passport.use(
  new JwtStrategy(JWT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, _onJwtStrategyAuth));

module.exports.jwtSettings = {
  expiresInMinutes: EXPIRES_IN_MINUTES,
  secret: SECRET,
  algorithm : ALGORITHM,
  issuer : ISSUER,
  audience : AUDIENCE
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options passed to `JwtStrategy` constructor must have a key `jwtFromRequest`.
It is missing in your code.

See https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt#usage

> **jwtFromRequest** (REQUIRED) Function that accepts a request as the only
>   parameter and returns either the JWT as a string or null. See
>   Extracting the JWT from the request for more details.

Comment: i think i use it look at this passport.use(
  new JwtStrategy(JWT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, _onJwtStrategyAuth));

Comment: `JWT_STRATEGY_CONFIG` must contain key `jwtFromRequest` but it is missing in code.